# Generate a fictitious stock option price variation

Tags: php, math

**What I do**

I am making graph of fictitious stock options.
The price is **updated each second**, with this function

```
function stockVariation($price,$max_up,$max_down)
{
    // Price > 1
    if($price > 1)
    {
        // Calculate
        $ratio=(mt_rand(0,$max_up/2)-mt_rand(0,$max_down/2))/1000;
        $price+=$ratio;
    }
    // Price <=1 (we don't want 0 or negative price...)
    else
    $price+=mt_rand(1,$max_up)/1000;

    return round($price,3);
}
```

I use a max_up and max_down values (from 10 to 100) to make the price change progressively and simulate some volatility.

For example, with max_up : 40 and max_down : 45, the price will progressively go down.

**My question**

But the problem, is that prices generated are too much volatile, even if max_up = max_down.
The result is "non-natural". (for example +10 points in one day for a base price of 15,000).

Result of price evolution per hour in 24 hour
[image: price evolution per hour in 24 hour]

Perhaps making round($price,4) and divisions by 10 000 instead of 1 000, will be better ?

If anyone have an idea or an advice to generate "natural" prices evolution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 86400 seconds in a day, so you'll need to divide by a much larger number.  And rather than adding and subtracting, you may want to multiply the current price by a factor that's slightly larger or smaller than 1.  That would simulate a percentage increase or decrease, rather than an absolute gain or loss.

```
function stockVariation($price, $max_up, $max_down)
{
  // Convert up/down to fractions of the current price.
  // These will be very small positive numbers.
  $random_up = mt_rand(0, $max_up) / $price;
  $random_down = mt_rand(0, $max_down) / $price;

  // Increase the price based on $max_up and decrease based on $max_down.
  // This calculates the daily change that would result, which is slightly
  // larger or smaller than 1.
  $daily_change = (1 + $random_up) / (1 + $random_down);

  // Since we're calling this function every second, we need to convert
  // from change-per-day to change-per-second.  This will make only a
  // tiny change to $price.
  $price = $price * $daily_change / 86400;

  return round($price, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Values displayed are round(price,3), if I divide by more, there will be no visible evolution in the last 2 minutes graph (real time), I guess.
With percents, big prices will grow bigest than small prices, I've also tried.

Comment: That's realistic, though: stock prices typically don't change very much from minute to minute, so you may want to display more precision.  If the changes must be large enough to be visible, they'll also be large enough to generate high volatility.  Alternatively, can you calculate a new price every minute instead of every second, and divide by 1440 instead of 86400?  That might make the changes more visible.

Comment: The real-time graph, is feed by seconds calculate. I copied/paste but you forgot ";" each line... ;-) After testing your solution, the Graph is flat... evolution is near of 0,000001. I think that the better way is to stock round($price,5) and divide by 100000 the ratio. Then I display only round($price,3). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oops - fixed; sorry, I don't speak PHP.  :-)  Thanks for the catch!  Glad you've got it working.

Comment: Validated anyway, now you can follow the... following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379261/stock-option-price-variations-by-users-orders-buy-sell :-)

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the idea, you could use an actual volatility number. If you want e.g. a volatility of 35%/year, you can find the volatility per second. In pseudocode:

```
vol_yr = 0.35
vol_month = vol_yr * sqrt(1.0/12)
vol_second = vol_yr * sqrt(1.0/(252 * 86400)) # or 365 * 86400
```

Then, every second, you "flip a coin" and either multiply or divide current stock price by (1 + vol_second). This is the principle of how binomial trees are created to evaluate exotic stock options.