# Stock option price variations by users orders (buy/sell)

Tags: php, math, stocks, stockquotes

Following this question [Generate a fictitious stock option price variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353938/generate-a-fictitious-stock-option-price-variation)

I wish to simulate that the price change, while users gives an order of buy or sell, like the real stock exchange. (I make a user case to help you to understand.)

**Initial state "Stock option example"** :

Company X, price of the stock option $20,000

A CRON task makes the price variation each second, with this PHP script :

```
function stockVariation($price,$max_up,$max_down)
{
    // Variation calculate, with volatility max (10 to 100)
    $ratio=(mt_rand(0,$max_up)-mt_rand(0,$max_down))/10000;
    // New price
    $price+=$ratio; 

    return round($price,5);
}
```

Volatility is made by random news which makes $max_up > $max_down or $max_up < max_down for a random time. Between, $max_up = $max_down.

Result in picture (1hour by minutes)
[image: Stock option price variation]

**User case "Buy example"** :

- A user send an order to buy 1000 of this option at $18,000
- The system store the order in database
- A CRON task verify each minute, if the price was <= to a buy order, the last minute
- When the price of this option <= to this order, the user gets this stock option.

**User case "Sell example"** :

- A user send an order to sell 1000 of this option at $22,000
- The system store the order in database
- A CRON task verify each minute, if the price was >= to a sell order, the last minute
- When the price of this option >= to this order, the user sells this stock option.

**My problem**

It works fine, but it is not a real variation of a stock exchange market.

**My question**

How to make the price variation by the prices and quantities of the orders ?

*Like the "law of supply and demand".*

For example (**edit regarding Peter answer**) :

```
function stockOrder($orderPrice,$orderQuantity,$type)//$type= buy or sell
{
    // Record the order in database (ok)
    // Compare with other orders (ok) 
    // $orderPrice<=$dbSellPrice or $orderPrice>=$dbBuyPrice
    if checks
       // Buy and sell at the best prices 
       // for quantities available holded by users (ok)
       // Record/update the holding of the stock (ok)
       // Update the price of the stock
    end if       
}
```

Perhaps I'm a little bit crazy to think that it could be possible to automatize that, but I believe in it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't want my code to be writen, I just want to have some help on the mathematic function to use for that ! Thank you very much for your down vote, my question is well formed and clear. Your comment is really not intestersting !

Comment: And you deleted it... ^^

Comment: Just some thoughts: It appears you intend both your `buyOrder()` and `sellOrder()` functions to take a price, which means they are effectively limit orders. With this in mind, the logic should be something like this: On receiving an order for a given price, search the database for a corresponding "matching" order and fulfill the order at the "correct" price, i.e. a price within the limit of each order. Then execute the order, removing the entries from the database and updating the last sold price.

Comment: With non-limit (market price) orders, you'd just immediately see what was available in the database of open orders and execute/fulfill.  The problem arises when you have multiple open, unfulfilled market-price orders. How to determine the price in this scenario? This would be almost like simulating a lack of liquidity, which could cause huge price swings.

Comment: Your comments are very interesting, I didn't saw the thing this way. Buy and sells prices directly by orders between users, more it is really coherent ! But what should I have to do with the final price ?... Like you say, it should cause huge price swings. An average price of the exchange between users and action price perhaps ?

Comment: And ratio by volumes/quantities buy/sell/current ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to expand on my comment a bit more.  Here is a basic scenario; assume we start from zero unfulfilled orders in the database/system.

1. User A submits a limit sell order for 20 units of Stock X @ $10.
2. User B submits a limit buy order for 10 units of Stock X @ $12.

After step 1, you will have one unfulfilled order in the system, since there are no open orders to match.

After step 2, the order User B submitted *can* be fulfilled by an open order in the system. (For simplicity, let's assume User A's order can be broken up, i.e. not an all-or-none order)

The reason User B's buy order can be fulfilled is for these two reasons:

1. There is an open sell sell order for a quantity greater than or equal to the buy order quantity.
2. The limit buy price is greater than or equal to the limit sell price, so a transaction price can be agreed upon.

User A doesn't want to sell for less than $10, and User B doesn't want to buy for more than $12. So in this case, there is a range of suitable transaction prices, i.e. any price between $10-12 is suitable.

The problem is finding the suitable transaction price. How to determine it? Pick the middle of the range? This is only one solution. (In a market with a lot of liquidity, you may not have this same sort of problem since there will be a lot of open orders at different prices and some at market price.)

For the sake of the example, let's say you picked a transaction price of $11, i.e. the middle of the suitable range.  User B's order would now be fulfilled and since User A's order was only partially fulfilled, there would be one open order left in the system: User A to sell their remaining 10 units at $10. The last trade price would be updated to $11.

Comment: Note that this is an *extremely* simplified system, but may form the basis of something more realistic/complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've already developed the system for selling "all or part" of the quantity. So in the case you describe, no matter with the current price of the stock ? ;-) Users makes the market ? For example, A order buy $20*10, B order sell $10*20, C order sell $15*5. The result will be : A buy $17.5*5 (to C) and A buy $15*5 (to B), so he gets 10 units of the stock $16.25 and it will also be the market price of the stock, isn't it ?

Comment: Generally, the "stock price" refers to the price at which the last trade executed, so yes, that makes sense. However, the stock price/last trade price is generally *not* an indication of what the *next* trade price will be, especially in volatile/low-liquidity markets.

Comment: I've updated the algorythm in my question regarding your work. What's about if I want the current price variation by sell/buy volumes too ? Because an order of 10 units and an order of 10000 units must not have the same impact to the stock price I figure, isn't it ?

Comment: Good point. However, in a real market, using the "last trade price" usually makes sense, since the speed of trades is such that small trading having an effect on the price is more than offset by the volume of other trade. And to answer your question: Small trades can have a drastic impact on the stock price in abnormal conditions. See this article about the May 2010 "Flash Crash": http://www.thestreet.com/story/10757383/how-pg-plunge-derailed-one-investor.html

Comment: Thanks for the article, very interesting. So the volumes exchanged have only a psychological impact on the market, and not mathematically on the stock prices ? (sorry for my bad english...)

Comment: Valky - that's my understanding. However, if someone submitted a huge market price order (i.e. no limit price), that would cause huge price swings. However, in a real stock market this is usually avoided by: 1) people breaking up their order into smaller chunks; 2) and the sheer size of the market (i.e. other orders) relative to the size of a single order.